# gnuplot with datetime problems

Tags: csv, datetime, gnuplot

## Data Format

My data is tab separated with a datetime as the first column.

```
datetime    gpsfix  lat lng state   serial  command voltage current kmph    Heartbeat   temperature rpm
2017-06-24 23:32:33.818000  True    37.2843 -80.4187    stopped False   off 12.03   0.2 0       27.2    0.0
2017-06-24 23:32:33.818000  True    37.2843 -80.4187    stopped False   off 12.03   0.2 0       27.2    0.0
```

## gnuplot-script.txt

```
# input data format
set datafile separator "\t"
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S"

# output format
set format x "%m-%d"
set grid

# plot the data
plot "5403940578.txt" using 1:2

pause -1
```

When I run `gnuplot gnuplot-script.txt`, I get an error:

```
plot "5403940578.txt" using 1:2
                               ^
"gnuplot-script.txt", line 11: x range is invalid
```

I'm sure that this is resulting from an inadequate understanding of the `datetime` format, but I have put enough time into it that I just need another pair of eyes.

Comment: You are attempting to plot values like "True", plot it using 1:3.

Comment: 3 issues here: 1) your data points are at the exact same location, 2) your timefmt is missing a percent in front of the `S`, 3) you should use `using 1:4` if you want to plot the `serial` column

Comment: @MichaelO. This was likely the issue.  I plotted `using 1:3` and magically, things started working.  @Thor thanks for the heads up on the percent, completely missed that.  What do you mean on point 1?  I have plotted data in the past `using 1:2` when it wasn't a date/time type with no issue.

Comment: @slightlynybbled:  Ad 1) Gnuplot complains when there is only one data point to plot. Ad 3) this may not be an issue depending on the format of your data file